# Display image in JSP using image url

Tags: html, image, src

I'm trying to display an image in a JSP page. The image is just a Google image and I'm passing the image URL to the src inside the JSP page.

Below is the code where I pass the link to the img markup

```
  <img src="http://tigerday.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Siberischer_tiger.jpg" width="100" height="100">
```

However the image doesn't get displayed; it only displays the box where the image should appear.

Comment: is your machine connected to internet?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Java, or JSP. It is a pure HTML question.

Comment: yes it is. I can just the link to browser and it loads the image.

Comment: i thing you need to refresh the jsp page

Comment: You spelled `src` incorrectly as `scr`.

Comment: In code there is typo.. 'scr' should be 'src'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check for `src` spelling in your `img` tag

make it correct

```
<img SRC="http://tigerday.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Siberischer_tiger.jpg" width="100" height="100">
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Fixed typo:

```
<img src="http://tigerday.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Siberischer_tiger.jpg" width="100" height="100">
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You got a typo over there:

```
  <img scr="http://tigerday.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Siberischer_tiger.jpg" width="100" height="100">
```

should be

```
  <img sRC="http://tigerday.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Siberischer_tiger.jpg" width="100" height="100">
```